# cannot load such file -- sprockets/processed_asset error after updating from rails 3.2 to 5.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

I've updated rails to version 5.0 and all other gems to fit this version and when I'm trying to lunch application I'm getting error: `cannot load such file -- sprockets/processed_asset`. Gem `sprockets` is now on version: 3.7.0. Any solution to this problem? TIA

Answer (score 1):

The problem was `gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'` which can't work with rails 5

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you upgrade your rails version to newest point release of every major versions. With this you will know each deprecations and changes particularly on configs from each versions you're jumping into.

- 3.2 -> 4.0
- 4.0 -> 4.1
- 4.1 -> 4.2
- 4.2 -> 5.0

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html